# Correct way to return value from try/catch

Tags: c#, ip-address

I have a method named `ValidIP()` that takes a `string` and returns `true` if the string is a valid IP address. Example 1 returns true after the `try`/`catch` statement because I don't care to catch an exception when returning the value. Example 2 returns the value directly after testing the string and while waiting for an exception in the try directive. Is this a matter of personal preference or is one example more correct or safer/less prone to crashing?

Example 1

```
private bool ValidIP(string ipAddress)
{
    try
    {
        IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Example 2

```
private bool ValidIP(string ipAddress)
{
    try
    {
        IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both programs are completely equivalent...

Comment: Besides the point but `private bool ValidIP(string ipAddress) { IPAddress tmp; return IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddress, out tmp);` is the best way. Then you don't ever have to deal with the overhead of throwing and catching a exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell both methods are equivalent. A more elegant way to solve this problem however is using the [`IPAddress.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
public static bool TryParse(string ipString,out IPAddress address)
```

The method returns `true` or `false` depending on whether it succeeded in parsing the address. Furthermore it uses an `out` parameter` such that you can immediately use the parsed IP address.

If you are only interested whether the IP address is valid, you can use a `dummy` IP address:

```
private bool ValidIP(string ipAddress) {
    IPAddress dummy;
    return IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddress,out dummy);
}
```

Furthermore note the important remark of the `Parse` and `TryParse` methods:

> Note that `TryParse` returns `true` **if it parsed the input successfully**,
>   but that this does **not necessarily mean that the resulting IP address
>   is a valid one.** Do not use this method to validate IP addresses.

Comment: I think this is the best solution, you're correct that the IPAddress already provides the TryParse() method, which is essentially what I was trying to create. Thanks Willem for helping me keep my head on straight.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way for the statement`return true` to throw an exception, so the two snippets are identical.  If you were performing some computation of the value you return that could actually throw an exception, and you want exceptions thrown there to result in the method throwing that exception, rather than returning false, then you'd need to use the latter approach.